# Sharing different media types from my own directories on Android

Tags: android, media, android-sdcard

I'm downloading files of various types (pictures, audio, videos) through my application. The folders mentioned in the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) under **"Saving files that should be shared"** don't exist, neither on the SD-cards of my actual device nor on those of my emulators.

However, creating them wouldn't hurt, but in this case I'd like to keep everything together within my applications folder, for example

`/mnt/sdcard/MYAPP/Pictures`.

But if I do that my pictures won't appear in the Media Gallery.

Is there any way to explicitly request Android to include the content of a specific directory into the Media Scanner?

Thanks alot
S.

Comment: I believe should show up in the stock android Gallery app, are they not??  AFAIK the only way to stop the Gallery from recursively checking each directory is to put a file named `.nomedia` at the root of that directory.

Comment: nope. the pictures I downloaded (jpegs + pngs) don't show up. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it took quite a while. But now it appears. Thanks anyways... :)